# How Fade-in and fade-out transitions between grid/list views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is for switch between grid and list views to display content. How to add *fade-in* and *fade-out* transitions or Opacity while switching between grid and list views.

*Here is Fiddle*: `http://jsfiddle.net/9B4Lp/3/` (demo, without transition)

***JS from Fiddle:***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var $box=jQuery(".post"),
        $bar=jQuery("a.bar_view");
    $dat=jQuery("a.dat_view");
    $dat.click(function () {
        $box.removeClass("bar");
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
        $bar.removeClass("active");
        jQuery.cookie("dat_style", 0);
        return false
    });
    $bar.click(function () {
        $box.addClass("bar");
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
        $dat.removeClass("active");
        jQuery.cookie("dat_style", 1);
        return false
    });
    if(jQuery.cookie("dat_style")==0) {
        $box.removeClass( "bar");
        $dat.addClass("active")
    } else {
        $box.addClass("bar");
        $bar.addClass("active")
    }
});
```

**I tried**:  when i add

`.fadeOut(1000)` to here `$box.removeClass("bar").fadeOut(1000);`

And  `.fadeIn(1000)` to here   `$box.addClass("bar").fadeIn(1000);`

it's **only** fade-In the Grid view, then List view invisible while fade-Out.

*See this Fiddle*: `http://jsfiddle.net/Qba5n/` (problem demo)

Please suggest How to fade-in and fade-out transitions between grid/list while switching?

***Note***: Please don't change HTML, don't provide any other HTML/plugin links.

Thanks :)

Comment: What you want to do when click on list????

Comment: fade-in on List view when click List link

Comment: My Question updated ..

Comment: Please suggest transitions for Both Views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated some code. I believe this is what you want..

[**Check Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4Cy9/1/)

Updated code:

```
$box.fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $box.removeClass("bar").fadeIn()//updated
    });

$box.fadeOut(1000,function(){
            $box.addClass("bar").fadeIn()//updated
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, But where is the Grid View `Fade-In` transitions ?

Comment: Please suggest transitions for Both Views.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's works! :) I can't vote for enough reputation point.